# Why does the form input send 0 value to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to send just the month (in string format) to the database.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
                $months = array();
                $currentMonth = date('m');

                for ($x = 1; $x < 13; $x++) {
                $months[] = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1));

                }

            ?>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:22px; margin-top:20px;">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Month of Payment </label>
            <div class="col-md-9"><?php echo form_multiselect('months[]', $months, $currentMonth-1, 'class="multiSel festivalSel col-md-9" '); ?> </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

This is the code i am using, it is passing as a string in the front end but displaying 0 in the database/datatables. This is using Codeignter framework, Any help will be appreciated, Thankyou :)

Comment: You try to insert values in the database?

Comment: put a var_dump of $_GET and $_POST into your controller. If it is missing there, then your stuff is not in a form.

Comment: Check you datatype of field you will assigned as  `int` that why you are getting 0

Answer (score 0):

try using these format to insert code

`date = \"".$date."\"`

add `\"` before and after .... may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

First of all u check the database structure what are you using variable type of date. If you use date time variable. Then your format string should be of yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s type.